# How can I prevent jQuery prepend() removing the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on the anchor tag, the image shifts from `div#left` to `div#right`. I want the image to be copied. Is this the default behaviour of `prepend()`? How can I avoid this problem?

The image is just a placeholder for a big div with many children.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left" style="float:left">
        <img src="Images/Rooms/K1.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="float:right"></div>
    <a id="addImageToRight" href="#">Add Image toRight</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addImageToRight").click(function () {
        var $image = $("#left img");
        var imgCopy = $image;
        $("div#right").prepend(imgCopy);
    });
});
```

Comment: `imgCopy` is not a copy. It is the same object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is this the default behaviour of prepend()?

Yes. Putting a DOM node somewhere in the document requires removing it from wherever in the document it is already. It can't exist in two places at the same time.

> ```
> var imgCopy = $image;
> ```

That copies the *value* of `$image` to `imgCopy`. The value is a *reference* to the object. (In JavaScript, variables can only every hold references to objects).

> How to avoid this problem?

Create a copy of the DOM node. Call `.clone()` on the jQuery object and prepend the return value.

```
var imgCopy = $image.clone();
```

Comment: Nice explanation . Thanks

Comment: I believe you could also store it as a property of an object, which would not be updated when the original got updated. For example, `img = {}; img.copy = $image;`. You may need to copy it into another object to prevent it from getting the reference: `imgCopy = {};imgCopy.copy = img.copy;`. Also, your names should probably be more inventive than mine.

Comment: @trysis — That makes no sense. You just end up copying references to different objects (and having much more confusing code). You never duplicate the DOM node itself.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that works with objects, but I guess not really with DOM nodes. I was just making a suggestion of another way, but if it doesn't actually work then nevermind.

Comment: @trysis — It doesn't work with objects. It does the exact opposite of what the goal is.

Answer (score 7):

You need to update your code from

```
 var $image = $("#left img");
 var imgCopy = $image;
```

to

```
 var imgCopy = $("#left img").clone();
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/R5yjTY06dKkqccwmxS62?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps take a look at jQuery's [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to create a copy of the img element.